# How do I control the cursor below the window?

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, netbeans-8, mouse-cursor

I want the cursor to manage everything normally, but through the window that is fixed on top, it is a window with opacity but the actions do not go through the window, how can I achieve that? it is with java netbeans 8.2

I have no idea how to make the window invisible to the cursor and just apply the window as a watermark to the entire screen.

Comment: *it is a window with opacity* - opacity has to be set to 0, otherwise mouse events are handled by the frame.

Comment: is that I want it to apply a tone to the entire screen, it is like a color filter type